# Points where $g(x):={ e }^{ (\left\| x \right\| ) }$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like to determine for which $x\in \mathbb{ R }^{ n }$ the function $g:\mathbb{ R }^{ n }\rightarrow [0,\infty )$ with $g(x):={ e }^{ (\left\| x \right\| ) }$
is one or two times differentiable and calculate the derivatives at those x

I unfortunately have never differentiated a function with a norm in it and I don't understand how to treat it and I couldn't find any working examples on the Internet. So my question is: how do I need to proceed to determine where this function is differentiable and how to treat the norm while differentiating?

Comment: Which norm is it ? Plus, the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable, it should help you to treat a lot of cases.

Comment: It isn't specified which norm it is in my book, but im assuming it's the euclidean norm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
g(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n)=e^{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\dotsb+x_n^2}}
$$
and it's simple to show that $g$ is differentiable for every $\vec x\neq\vec 0$. In $\vec x=\vec 0$ we have
$$
\lim_{h_i\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{g(0, 0, \dotsc, 0, h_i, 0\dotsc, 0)-1}{h_i}=
\lim_{h_i\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{e^{h_i}-1}{h_i}=1\\
\lim_{h_i\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{g(0, 0, \dotsc, 0, h_i, 0\dotsc, 0)-1}{h_i}=
\lim_{h_i\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{e^{-h_i}-1}{h_i}=-1
$$
(because $g(0, 0, \dotsc, 0, h_i, 0\dotsc, 0)=e^{\lvert h_i\rvert}$) then $g$ is not differentiable at $\vec x=\vec 0$.

Comment: Maybe you could make a remark that this computation works for any norm. We just have $$ \lim_{h_i \rightarrow 0^{\pm}} \frac{e^{\vert h_i \vert \cdot \Vert e_i \Vert}-1}{h_i} = \pm \Vert e_i \Vert. $$

Comment: This is true in order to show that $g$ is not differentiable in $\vec 0$, but for $\vec x\neq \vec 0$ depends strongly from the chosen norm.

Comment: Yes, of course, that is why I said "this computation". In generally it will not be differentiable (like for the supremum norm in several variables).